# carousel android error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'UseReflection' in package

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, carousel

when implementing a carousel i am having problem with my xml file. The main.xml layout is showing the following error

Multiple annotations found at this line:

```
- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'UseReflection' in package 
 ''
- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'SelectedItem' in package 
 ''
- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'Items' in package ''

- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'Names' in package 
 ''
```

the main layout looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:pj="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/packagename"

    xmlns:bm="package name"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical"
>

     <TextView

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_weight="0.5"

        android:text="text"

        android:id="@+id/selected_item"

        android:background="#1E1921"

        android:textColor="#A85E4F"

        android:textStyle="normal"

        />

   <package.controls.Carousel 

         android:id="@+id/carousel"

         android:layout_width="413dp"

         android:layout_height="446dp"

         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

         pj:Items="@array/entries"

         pj:Names="@array/names"

         pj:SelectedItem="0"

         pj:UseReflection="true" >

     </package.controls.Carousel>

</LinearLayout>
```

The attrs.xml in my value folder

```
<resources>

        <declare-styleable name="Carousel">

        <attr name="android:gravity" /> 

        <attr name="android:animationDuration" />

        <attr name="UseReflection" format="boolean"/>

        <attr name="Items" format="integer"/>

        <attr name="SelectedItem" format="integer"/>

        <attr name="maxTheta" format="float"/>

        <attr name="minQuantity" format="integer"/>

        <attr name="maxQuantity" format="integer"/>

        <attr name="Names" format="string" />

    </declare-styleable>    

</resources>
```

is it an eclipse error or i miss an step. can help please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you properly replaced `packagename` by your actual application's package name (like com.myapp) ?

```
xmlns:pj="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/packagename"
```

should be

```
xmlns:pj="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.myapp"
```

Additionally, your attribute names should start with a lower-case letter as per android conventions.